# Error in installing 'RPostgreSQL' package

Tags: r

I am trying to install PostgreSQL package on R version 3.1.2. running on Linux.

I get the following error...

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/src/contrib/RPostgreSQL_0.4.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 477352 bytes (466 Kb) opened URL



==================================================
downloaded 466 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘RPostgreSQL’ ...
** package ‘RPostgreSQL’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
sh: ./configure: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RPostgreSQL’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/RPostgreSQL’

> The downloaded source packages are in
>         ‘/tmp/RtmpANw7OS/downloaded_packages’ Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library' Making 'packages.html' ... done Warning
> message: In install.packages("RPostgreSQL") :   installation of here`package ‘RPostgreSQL’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks odd:

> `./configure: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied`

Is your `/bin/sh` unsual or in bad shape?  What happens when you (manually) untar the sources and run `./configure` ?

Comment: Didn't try that... This is the first time I have hit an installation snag on the system... not sure what you mean by /bin/sh unsual or in bad shape